# ruby net/http openssl security level

Tags: ruby, openssl, net-http

Is it possible to set security level in ruby when calling net::http instead of modifying openssl config?

I found out that OpenSSL has a way how to set security level through

```
OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext#security_level
```

but how can I use it in new Net::Http request?

When I just setup

```
ctx = OpenSSL::SSL::SSLContext.new
ctx.security_level = 1
```

it is ignored by http request